# How to create 1 to N files with a user input file name and file number?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a homework really important for tomorrow. I have to create a batch file.

The batch code has to ask the user to enter a name and a number. That number must be greater than 0 and less than 100.

Let's say the user enters `hello` and `2`. Then the batch file should create the two files `hello_1.txt` and `hello_2.txt` in current directory.

The problem is that I have no idea of how to do it and it's really important. I've been in hospital for the last week. So I could not go to school and missed those lessons.

The cmd window should look similar to:

```
hello 2 

Creation of 2 files:

hello_1.txt
hello_2.txt
```

Here is what I have already:

```dos
@echo off

set /p text=Enter a name
set /p number=Enter a number
set /a N=%number%
if %N% LSS 1 goto error
if %N% GTR 99 goto error
for /l %%i in (1,1,%N%) do (
    mkdir %text%_%N%.txt
)
goto end

:error
echo Check your number (between 1 and 100)

:end
echo Script OK
```

Comment: [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html), expecially `/p` and `Modulo` and  [For /l](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) should get you a good start. Come back, when you have specific problems.

Comment: @Stephan can u check my code pls ? I dont know how to create the file N times, it only creates one time and it creates a dir and not a file...

Comment: `mkdir %text%_%N%.txt`? Probably `mkdir %text%_%%i.txt`. But this creates a directory. To create a file, one of many methods is `break>%text%_%%i.txt`

Comment: yes thank you ! But you made a little mistake, if I use break>... it only creates 1 file, i had to write break>>%text%_%%i.txt but thank you !

Comment: `>` writes a new file /overwrites, if already existing. `>>` appends to a file (creates, if not existing). Doesn't make a difference here. Probably you forgot the `)` with your first try.

Answer (score 2):

The simple version of the batch file for this task which is not fail safe against invalid input.

```
@echo off
set /P "text=Enter a name: "

:PromptNumber
set /P "number=Enter a number: "
set /A N=number 2>nul
if %N% LSS  1 goto PrintError
if %N% GTR 99 goto PrintError

echo/
for /L %%I in (1,1,%N%) do echo Create "%text%_%%I.txt" 2>"%text%_%%I.txt"
echo/
pause
goto :EOF

:PrintError
echo/
echo Check your number which must be between 1 and 100.
echo/
goto PromptNumber
```

If environment variable `number` is not defined after prompting the user because the user has not entered anything at all, the value `0` is assigned to environment variable `N`. That happens also if the entered string is not a valid decimal, octal or hexadecimal number. The error message output to handle **STDERR** on invalid number string is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

A **FOR** loop with option `/L` is used to create the files from 1 in incrementing steps of 1 to value of `N`.

The **ECHO** command outputs which file is created at the moment. The **ECHO** command has no error output because it can't fail which makes it an ideal candidate here to create the file with 0 bytes file size by redirecting **STDERR** of command **ECHO** to the file to create.

I have also a second version being much more fail safe against invalid or unexpected input. I do not recommend to present it to your teacher as it is obviously that a novice in batch file coding has not written it.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:PromptName
set "FileName="
echo/
set /P "FileName=Enter a name: "

rem Has the user entered anything at all?
if not defined FileName goto PromptName

rem Remove all double quotes from file name string?
set "FileName=!FileName:"=!"

rem Is the file name string now an empty string?
if not defined FileName goto PromptName

rem The string can be still invalid as file name. So check on
rem first file creation if the file could be created successfully.
(set /P FileNumber=<nul >"!FileName!_1.txt") 2>nul
if not exist "!FileName!_1.txt" (
    echo/
    echo The string !FileName! is most likely not valid for a file name.
    goto PromptName
)

:PromptNumber
set "FileNumber="
echo/
set /P "FileNumber=Enter a number in range 1 to 99: "

rem Has the user entered anything at all?
if not defined FileNumber goto PromptNumber

rem Has the file number string any other character than digits?
for /F "delims=0123456789" %%I in ("!FileNumber!") do (
    echo/
    echo !FileNumber! is not a valid decimal number.
    goto PromptNumber
)

rem It is safe now to reference the file number consisting
rem only of digits 0-9 without usage of delayed expansion.

rem Has the file number more than two digits?
if not "%FileNumber:~2%" == "" (
    echo/
    echo %FileNumber% has more than two digits.
    goto PromptNumber
)

rem Remove first digit of number if the number has two digits and
rem the first digit is 0 to get the number later always interpreted
rem as expected as decimal number and not as octal number.
if not "%FileNumber:~1%" == "" if "%FileNumber:~0,1%" == "0" set "FileNumber=%FileNumber:~1%"

rem The file number is now in range 0 to 99. But 0 is not allowed.
if "%FileNumber%" == "0" (
    echo/
    echo Number 0 is not in valid range.
    goto PromptNumber
)

rem Create the remaining files. The first one was created already before.
echo/
echo Create "!FileName!_1.txt"
for /L %%I in (2,1,%FileNumber%) do echo Create "!FileName!_%%I.txt" 2>"!FileName!_%%I.txt"
echo/
endlocal
pause
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) and take a look on Microsoft's [command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) as well as SS64's [A-Z index of the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/). DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) explains why in both batch files `echo/` is used instead of often used `echo.` for printing an empty line to console.

Comment: I have always just used `TYPE NUL>File.txt`.